# MonoDevelop on Mac - Export Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macos, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We are having a new developer (well versed in Visual Studio) start working in MonoTouch on the Mac.

I have my settings in MonoDevelop (after using for a while) setup exactly like Visual Studio:

- Hotkeys like F5, F6, F10, Ctrl+J, Ctrl+., etc.
- Code formatting
- Modified and additional code snippets

Is there a way to export these and import on another machine?  I don't mind to manually copy files.  I'm using MonoDevelop 2.8.6.4 (should be latest non-beta right now).

I'd also like to put my settings up on GitHub if this is something that is possible.  I know a lot of .Netters would make use of it.

Comment: On the other hand, on a MacBook Pro without an external keyboard, having to press `fn` to use the `Fxx` buttons doesn't seem to be very effective =/

Comment: You can toggle that setting, that is one of the first things I do with a new mac.  I have to use fn for volume, etc., but I am fine with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything should be in `/Users/whatever/Library/MonoDevelop-2.6` or whatever your version is

Comment: Thanks! If you really put them up on GitHub, please leave a comment with the URL - I'd pull them in a second!

Comment: For others looking for this, here is an updated set for Xamarin Studio: https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils/tree/develop/KeyBindings These will get merged into my main branch soon.